# Meaning of "Have worked" and "worked"

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, sentence-structure

Is there any meaning diffrence in below sentences?

I have worked on this software when I was in college

Or

I worked on this software when I was in college

Comment: Another possibility: *"I **had** worked on this software when I was in college"*, In fact, this one looks better and relevant.

Comment: @Maulik: There isn't really any concept of "better" or "more relevant", since OP's example doesn't contain any additional context. If it's within a past tense narrative you'd use past perfect *(**had** worked on it)* to indicate that this occurred earlier than the actual "narrative time". If the context is present tense (speaker ***is*** now talking about something in the past), simple past is the only valid option.

Answer (score 0):

The former sentence is not correct grammatically.  You cannot use the present perfect apart from the case mentioned by StoneyB and FumbleFingers, the present simple, or even the future simple in the main clause if the when-clause is in the past.

On the other hand, the latter sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: I don't believe that assertion. There's nothing ungrammatical about, say, *I've eaten snails before, when I lived in France*.

Comment: FumbleFingers, That makes sense. Please tell me  if you  can omit the adverb "before" in your sentence.

Comment: Thanks to [clarification from @StoneyB](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59564/meaning-of-have-worked-and-worked/59567?noredirect=1#comment113999_59567) I now see that the ***comma*** is pivotal (the word ***before*** in my example helps, but isn't *vital* for grammaticality). Anyway, because of that I've cancelled my downvote, having made my point.